# Error calling REST API in Firefox

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, javascript, rest

I am using Rest API for Follow Functionality. My JS is working fine on IE but it doesn't work on Firefox(neither it goes under success call function neither under error. Is anyone having any idea about this.
Below is my piece of code i am  using:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
   SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {  
 SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(isAlreadyFollowed, 'SP.js');  
}, 'SP.runtime.js');  
});

// Get the url of the current page
function getUrl() {
var ctxCurrent = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var url = ctxCurrent.get_url();
var docUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + url ;
return docUrl;}

function isAlreadyFollowed() {
var followingManagerEndpoint = getUrl() + "/_api/social.following";
$.ajax( {
    url: followingManagerEndpoint + "/isfollowed",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify( { 
        "actor": {
            "__metadata": {
                "type":"SP.Social.SocialActorInfo"
            },
            "ActorType":1,
            "ContentUri":getUrl(),
            "Id":null
        } 
    }),
    headers: { 
        "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose",
        "content-type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest":$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function (responseData) { 
        stringData = JSON.stringify(responseData);
        jsonObject = JSON.parse(stringData);
        if (jsonObject.d.IsFollowed === true ) {
            alert('The user is currently following the document.');
            //stopFollowDocument();
        }
        else {
            alert('The user is currently NOT following the document.');
            //followDocument();
        }
    },
    error: requestFailed
});}

 function requestFailed(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert('Error:\n' + xhr.status + '\n' + thrownError + '\n' + xhr.responseText);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the code is working properly in IE, please make sure that [MIME type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#scriptingLanguages) is set to `text/javascript` for script tag where the code is declared.

Replace:

```
<script type="text/jscript">
```

with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```